# React 15 + Typescript: React.FormEvent<T> typings are incomplete?

Tags: reactjs, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

The onChange attribute for a textarea form wants a `React.EventHandler<React.FormEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>>`.

Down the rabbit hole and we find that

```
interface EventHandler<E extends SyntheticEvent<any>> {
    (event: E): void;
}

type FormEventHandler<T> = EventHandler<FormEvent<T>>;

/* ... */

interface FormEvent<T> extends SyntheticEvent<T> {
}
```

In other words, onChange simply wants a function that takes a FormEvent and returns void, and FormEvent currently is identical to  SyntheticEvent.

The problem is that `SyntheticEvent<T>.target: EventTarget`, and `EventTarget` does not define `value`.

I noticed that there's also `currentTarget: EventTarget & T`, where T is `HTMLTextInputArea`, and that seems to have value defined. But the [form handling pages show](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html) `event.target` being looked at, not `event.currentTarget`. What's the difference? Should I follow the typings or the doc?

Edit: I answered my own question. `currentTarget` is the element I've bound the handler to, and `target` is that element that received the action which precipitated this event. I suppose I always want to read value from `currentTarget`, so in this case, I think the typings are leading me right and the docs are leading me wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Your edit is correct.

This is a simple issue, but the infamous `currentTarget`/`target` conundrum has unfortunately lead to an amusing edit war of React typings.
The reason the React docs use `target` is because it makes no difference on a child element and that they value simplicity as explicated here:

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/9279

If you need a more thorough reference to freshen things up, you can read one of my interventions on this subject:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/11508#issuecomment-256045682